# GIT : tracking untracked files

Tags: git, addition

When making changes to existing files, the following commands are used.

```
> git checkout myBranch
---Make code changes to myFile1.c and myFile2.c
> git add src/myFile1.c
> git add src/myFile2.c
> git commit -m "My Sample" 
> git push

----Go to server
> Pull....
```

The above pulls the changes done to the 2 files to the remote repository.

**"untracked" files**

Every so often I see "untracked" files in my local repository.
From my understanding, "untracked" files are files newly inserted into the remote repository (and being tracked there) but now downloaded to my local repository but not officially tracked yet. Is this correct?

Based on research, it appears the way to add the "untracked" files to the local repository is to do a "git add ...".

Incorporating the "git add ..." to the above example, I get the following :

```
> git checkout myBranch
> git add --all     <-------Adding the "untracked" files. 
---Make code changes to myFile1.c and myFile2.c
> git add src/myFile1.c
> git add src/myFile2.c
> git commit -m "My Sample" 
> git push

----Go to server
> Pull
```

In the example at the very top, the commit, push and pull resulted in the 2 modified files eventually getting pulled to the remote repository. Now in this example, won't this result in both my changes in the two files as well as all the "untracked" files eventually get Pulled to the server?

Comment: `git add --all` adds all files that have your changes (unstaged files) that either tracked or untracked.

Comment: Yes, but won't the "add", "commit", "push" then "pull" result in all the files with and without changes get sent back to the remote repository?

Comment: `add` adds files to staging, its a kind of status that filters files that are needed to be committed. `commit` basically saves those changes to your local repository. `push` pushes those changes to remote repository too. `pull` on the other hand, pulls those changes from the remote repository to your local repository.

Comment: So, "add" has duel purpose with one being to add untracked files and two being to add modified files.  If I am understanding, the "commit" is smart enough to know the difference between the two???

Comment: both the purposes are basically same, it is just used for adding pending files (can be untracked files or modified files) to the staged files, that are later on committed.

Comment: One thing that helped me in understanding git's way of working was: "Git does *not* track files, it tacks changes." In this context there is no need to distinguish between modifying some file or adding a new file to the repo. It's simply modifications in the repo's content. *And now just for my understanding:* What do you mean by "Go to server" then "pull"? Does't "server" refer to the central (bare) repo (`origin` in git speak)?

Answer (score 0):

Your question makes me wonder do you have identical `.gitignore` files across your branches?

Because if you don't, different sets of files will be ignored when you're switching from branch to branch. Meaning if some files were ignored in one branch, `git` does not care  about them when switching to `myBranch`, it leaves them untouched on the disk. But as soon as your branch is changed, new `.gitignore` from that branch get delivered to the folder, resulting different set of ignoring rule to be applied.

As result some files could be excluded from ignored and showed as `untracked`.

I would recommend go to https://www.gitignore.io/ and generate `.gitignore` file that suits your project technologies best. And make sure you have that `.gitignore` delivered to all your branches.

Comment: Would i want to ignore these files? What if I need to eventually modify one of these files?